# Configure Frame Size Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter code with multiple frames, but I don't understand how to change each frame size. I tried with the .configure() method but it didn't work, I would like that each frame to have the same size as the window the "master".

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# ---- FrontEnd ----
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master  

        self.master.title('MediaTools')  
        self.master.geometry("500x480") 
        
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master) 

        # Frame 1 and 2
        frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        label1 = ttk.Label(frame1, text = "This is Window One")
        label1.pack(pady = 50, padx = 20)
        label2 = ttk.Label(frame2, text = "This is Window Two")
        label2.pack(pady = 50, padx = 20)
 
        frame1.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        frame2.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Change the size of frame1
        frame1.configure(width=400, height=300)
        frame2.configure(width=400, height=300)

        self.notebook.add(frame1, text = "Validación de archivos")
        self.notebook.add(frame2, text = "Validación de información")
 
        # Frame 3
        frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook) 
         
        label3 = ttk.Label(frame3, text = "Proceso")
        label3.pack(pady = 50, padx = 20)
         
        frame3.pack(fill= tk.BOTH, expand=True) 
        frame3.configure(width=400, height=300)
 
        self.notebook.insert("end", frame3, text = "Proceso")
        self.notebook.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, expand = True)
         
 
root = tk.Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The app currently looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the frames, it's with the notebook. Since you're using `pack`, you need to instruct it to fill the space that has been allocated to it.

Setting `expand` to `True` will cause the packer to expand *the allocated space* for the notebook, but does not cause the widget to fill the allocated space. You must set `fill` to `"both"` (or `tk.BOTH`) if you expect the widget to fill the space allocated for it.

```
self.notebook.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, expand = True, fill="both")
#                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note: the size of the frames is ignored for the following reasons:

1. By default when using `pack` frames will shrink or grow to fit their contents, so even though you're trying to set the size of the frames, the actual size is determined by the labels placed in the frame.
2. Because you are using a notebook, the notebook will grow or shrink to fit the frames that are inside it.
3. Because you set the geometry of the window as a whole, all of these sizes will be adjusted to fit the requested size of the window when you set `expand` and `fill` of the notebook as suggested in this answer.

To cut all of that down to a simpler statement: setting the size of the inner frames is pointless since the size of the frames are dependent on their contents, and on the size of the window as a whole.